# Error problems with typescript react native

Tags: typescript, react-native, eslint

Can someone help to pointed out where the actual problem of this issue?[image]

the code run properly in the emulator but it seems to have error on formatting, i have try to find answer but still no solved for that, any help on how to configure it?

Comment: Your question is too vague, and will most likely get flagged for removal. When asking questions on SO, please isolate the issue yourself and explain in clear terms what you are trying to achieve and your steps to troubleshoot it. Questions that provide no context are both difficult to answer, and provide no long term benefit to the community.

Comment: Post your code instead of an screenshot. There a several issues I can see.